# EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found with express, typeorm, jest

Tags: express, jestjs, typeorm

**auth.model.ts**

```
import { AppDataSource } from "../app-data-source";
import { User } from "../entity";

class AuthModel {
  static register = async (userDTO: RegisterUserDTO) => {
    try {
      const userRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(User);
      const user = userRepo.create(userDTO);
      await userRepo.save(user);
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error(err);
      throw {
        status: 500,
        message: err.message,
      };
    }
  };
}

export default AuthModel;
```

**app-data-source.ts**

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import config from "./config";
import { User } from "./entity";

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: config.database.type,
  host: config.database.host,
  port: config.database.port,
  username: config.database.username,
  password: config.database.password,
  database: config.database.name,
  entities: [User],
  synchronize: true,
});
```

**user.entity.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, Generated } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: "user" })
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid", { name: "id" })
  userId: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 100, nullable: false, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255, nullable: false })
  password: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255, default: "", nullable: true })
  introduce: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255, name: "profile_img", default: "", nullable: true })
  profileImage: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "datetime", name: "created_at_date", nullable: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 100, nullable: false, unique: true })
  nickname: string;

  @Column({ type: "boolean", name: "is_auth_flag", default: false, nullable: true })
  isAuth: boolean;
}

export default User;
```

I make API Server with Express + TypeORM + Mysql

if i send post with postman then success
[Postman Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3EOj.png)

but i test with jest then throw **EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4E9n.png)

Postman is Success.. but test with jest is throw error

please help me

- change entities attribute on **app-data-source.ts**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `ConfigurationProvider`.
Where you gonna pass:

```
private generateConfiguration(environment? : Config) : Config {
  return {
    db : {
      type: 'mysql',
      entities: [entity_path + '/../**/*.entity.ts']
    }
  }
}
```